# Algorithm to get similar thematic text by tag frequency

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm

I have bunch of text (title + message) and I want to add tags for them. I processed each text by this way:

1. ignore articles, pronouns, etc ('a', 'an', 'the', 'him', 'them' etc)
2. ignore hyphenation
3. preserve proper nouns

and get kind of tags for each text and number of its entry.

Now i have table of relation frequency of tags and text ids:

```
                 tag_id1 | tag_id2 | tag_id3 | tag_id4
      text_id1  | 10     |  1      | 3       |   1   
      text_id2  | 1      |  1      | 1       |   1
      text_id3  | 13     |  0      | 2       |   0
      text_id4  | 9      |  1      | 2       |   1
      text_id5  | 0      |  0      | 0       |   0
```

How can i determine by mysql query a similar text for text_id1? 
I want to get something like sorted list
text_id3
text_id4
text_id2

"Jaccard similarity" algo is not enough because its only calculate tags relation

Comment: . . Can you define what "similar" means?  Or are you looking for that definition online?

Answer (score 1):

One measure of similar is the absolute value of the difference in each tag field.  You could calculate that in SQL like this:

```
select t2.name, abs(t1.tag_id1-t2.tag_id1)+abs(t1.tag_id2-t2.tag_id2)+
abs(t1.tag_id3-t2.tag_id3)+abs(t1.tag_id4-t2.tag_id4) score from 
tag t1, tag t2 where t1.name='text_id1' and t2.name != 'text_id1' 
order by score asc;
+----------+-------+
| name     | score |
+----------+-------+
| text_id4 |     2 |
| text_id3 |     6 |
| text_id2 |    11 |
| text_id5 |    15 |
+----------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You could interpret your text characterizations as vectors, with the tags as dimensions (or rather a basis, if you are deeply into linear algebra). You can then compute the dot product between texts to rate similarity.

This will reward high frequencies in a common tag, but not actively punish tags with a high frequency in one text but a low frequency in the other. So a long text which talks about most tags in many places will be ranked higher than a short text with only a few tags, but those tags very similar to the reference text. If that is a problem, you might improve the situations by using relative instead of absolute frequencies, i.e. multiply frequencies by a common factor such that their sum equals 1 (or 100 or whatever) for every text.

Doing this computation would be easier if your frequencies were only in a single column, with text and tag id in two other columns. Suppose you had a table called `freqs` with columns `text_id`, `tag_id` and `frequency`. Then you could do something like

```sql
SELECT t2.text_id, SUM(t1.frequency * t2.frequency) AS score
FROM freqs AS t1, freqs AS t2
WHERE t1.text_id = ?           -- insert the ID of the reference text
  AND t2.text_id <> t1.text_id -- different text
  AND t1.tag_id = t2.tag_id    -- but same tag
GROUP BY t2.text_id            -- one result for every text
ORDER BY score DESC            -- closest text first
```

You can see this in action at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a6af7/4